# Neki'at yada'im

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

[The Kitzur shulchan aruch 2:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.2.6?lang=bi&with=Halakhah&lang2=en) says that one says " Al Nekiyat Yadayim" when there is no water available.

What are the opinion of sefardic poskim? Is it the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Shulchan Aruch* ([OC 4:22](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x348)) says the same (and is actually the source for the *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch*).

Answer (score 0):

I checked and it also says in Yalkut yosef 4:75 and also [Peninei halacha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-08-01/) says the same. Thank you very much for @Ploni's answer.